# What happens on charge failure | Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm looking through stripes api and documentation to draft some logic as to what will happen when a payment is not successful. [The api shows](https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors) the following code containing a specific exception for when a card is declined:

```
try {
  // Use Stripe's library to make requests...
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Error\Card will be caught
  $body = $e->getJsonBody();
  $err  = $body['error'];

  print('Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n");
  print('Type is:' . $err['type'] . "\n");
  print('Code is:' . $err['code'] . "\n");
  // param is '' in this case
  print('Param is:' . $err['param'] . "\n");
  print('Message is:' . $err['message'] . "\n");
}
```

However, If you look at [the charge object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object), it contains an outcome object with properties that contain details as to the status of the charge (approved_by_network, declined_by_network, not_sent_to_network, and reversed_after_approval).

```
Stripe\Charge JSON: {
  "outcome": {
    "network_status": "approved_by_network",
    "reason": null,
    "risk_level": "normal",
    "seller_message": "Payment complete.",
    "type": "authorized"
  }
}
```

My question then becomes, if an exception is thrown when a charge is declined, how could you then check the outcome properties of the charge object? My current thought would be to check the charge outcome object properties inside of the try catch block, however I feel as if there might be something I'm missing or don't fully understand? I guess I'm just looking for some reassurance that that is the proper way to handle this.

Comment: note, that exception has `The ID of the failed charge.`, in catch block you can retrieve that charge and get more details

Comment: @Lashane That makes sense. So one would execute the charge in the try catch block, and if it completes then you know its successful, then if the exception is thrown you can use the charge value of the exception to obtain details as to why that charged failed.

Comment: Also, you should set up a webhook to receive the outcome. The payment can be disputed. You should be aware of that too.

Comment: @RifatulIslamChayon Can you link to documentation describing this scenario? Appreciate the input.

Comment: @commanderZiltoid, https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks